# Discord.py | Pillow в Embed

Tags: python, discord.py, pillow

У меня есть код который работает с библиотекой Pillow. \

**Задача кода**: Пользователь должен написать команду после, так же в сообщении команды написать любой текст. После бот отправляет определенное изображение в котором и будет присутствовать заданный пользователем текст. 
Проще говоря, это как сообщение от бота только с немного оформлением.
Так вот, мой код работает отлично, только я бы хотел чтобы он отправлялся в виде Embed, а не простого сообщения. Как я могу добавить созданный файл в Embed?

**Дополнительно**: если вам известно как сделать ограничение в символах, например в изображении может вмещаться только 30 символов, но так как этого ограничения самого то нет, то все символы просто будут выходить за грани изображения. А если добавить ограничение, и если пользователь захочет написать текст в котором более 30 символов, то бот отправит ему предупреждение.
[Дополнительный вопрос не обязателен] Буду рад если поделитесь ответом.

**1 Изображение** (*achievement.png*) 
**2 Изображение** (*exit.png*) 
**3 Изображение** (*дополнительно*)

```
@Bot.command()
async def achievement(ctx, *, text):

    text1 = text
    achievement = Image.open("achievement.png")
    colors = ["white"]
    drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(achievement)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("F77 Minecraft.ttf", 15)
    for color in colors:
        drawer.text((60, 35), text=text1, font=font, fill=color)

    achievement.save("exit.png")

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("exit.png"))
```

[image: Первое]
[image: Дополнительно]
[image: Второе]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы отправить изображение в виде `embed`, замените строку

```
await ctx.send(file = discord.File("exit.png"))
```

На этот фрагмент кода:

```
file = discord.File("exit.png", filename="exit.png")
embed = discord.Embed(color = discord.Colour.gold())
embed.set_image(url="attachment://exit.png")
await ctx.send(file = file, embed = embed)
```

**Результат:** *(у меня нет шрифта из MineCraft, поэтому Arial)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если вы хотите добавить какие-то надписи, то в форме `embed`, помимо `color` можно указать значения `title` и `description`.

**Пример:**

```
embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Достижение', description = 'Получено новое достижение!', color = discord.Colour.gold())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Поменять цвет `embed` можно на любой другой, вот [список цветов](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=colour#discord.Colour)**

---

Что насчет ограничения в 30 символов - узнать длину сообщения можно через встроенную функцию `len()`

**Пример использования:**

```
@Bot.command()
async def achievement(ctx, *, text):
    text1 = text
    if len(text1) >= 30:
        # выводим сообщение об ошибке
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, длина текста не должна превышать **30**', colour = discord.Color.red()))
        # используем return, чтобы завершить функцию
        return
    else:
        # здесь ваш остальной код
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает.

Comment: А если картинка просто не добавляется? Игнорирует

Comment: @QuL1ux возможно путь неправильно указан или еще какая-нибудь мелочь. Попробуйте обернуть содержимое команды в `try-except`, может обработается какая-нибудь ошибка

Comment: Ошибок тоже нету, путь указан правильно. А для чего в пути указание "attachment"?

Comment: Потому что файл подгружается не с компа, а из вложения в дискорде. Если у метода set_image есть параметр file или что-то такое, вместо url, то можно путь к файлу с компа указать

Comment: Но там вроде только ссылку можно указывать: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.set_image